# BxSlider Carousel vertical-arrow vertical as well

Tags: jquery, css, html, bxslider

I am using bxSlider for carousel. It provides horizontal and vertical mode which fine.

Only issue is when displaying vertical, arrows still remain on horizontal position.

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="sliderLocation">
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar6"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar7"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar8"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar9"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar10"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.sliderLocation').bxSlider({
  slideWidth: 200,
  minSlides: 3,
  maxSlides: 3,
  moveSlides: 1,
  slideMargin: 10,
  pager: false,
  mode: 'vertical'
});
```

**CSS**
See online. I am using default one: http://bxslider.com/

[image]

And vertical:
Arrows coming in left and right side, I want those to move to top and bottom:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using CSS.

This is what seemed to work for me:

```css
.bx-wrapper .bx-prev {
  left: calc(50% - 16px) !important;
  top: -2em !important;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-next {
  right: calc(50% - 16px) !important;
  top: calc(100% + 2em) !important;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Comment: This is cool, But I need Horizontal slider on same page as well. So if mode is vertical then only buttons need to be on top otherwise leave as current.

Comment: Cool - well all you need to do then is put the vertical slider inside it's own div with a unique id, let's say `#vert-slide` and then prefix both those rules with the id, i.e. `#vert-slide .bx-wrapper .bx-prev {....`

Answer (score 2):

Override the styles from `bxslider.css` in a `custom.css`, as shown below.

**Note:** I had to use important because of the snippet but if you put the `custom.css` after the `bxslider.css` and use specificity properly, you won't need the `!important`

```js
$('.sliderLocation').bxSlider({
  slideWidth: 200,
  minSlides: 3,
  maxSlides: 3,
  moveSlides: 1,
  slideMargin: 10,
  pager: false,
  mode: 'vertical'
});
```

```css
/*Custom CSS that should put after BxSlider.css file*/

.bx-wrapper {
  margin-top: 50px !important
}
.bx-controls a {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  left: 45% !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  bottom: 0!important;
  right: 0 !important;
}
.bx-controls .bx-prev {
  top: -30px !important;
}
.bx-controls .bx-next {
  top: 350px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<div class="sliderLocation">
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar6">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar7">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar8">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar9">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar10">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is working thanks, But I need Horizontal slider on same page as well. So if mode is vertical then only buttons need to be on top otherwise leave as current

Comment: just give an `ID` to the div where you have the class `sliderLocation` for the vertical slider

Comment: Both solutions working but stack-overflow allowing only one to select